# Open and closed round balls in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are convex

Tags: metric-spaces

I don't know what a round ball is. I hope this is just an unnecessary Detail but if this is important to solve this excercise please let me know.

The original text is in German:

Offene und abgeschlossene runde Bälle in $\mathbb{R}^n$ sind konvex.

My thoughts are:

A subset $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex if and only if I take two arbitrary Points $a,b\in X$ then $\forall t\in[0,1]$ $a+t(b-a)=x_t\in X$.

I also know what a closed and open ball is. 
$B(x, r) = \{y ∈ X : d(x, y) < r\}$

where $X$ is $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $d(x,y)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+...+(x_n-y_n)^2}$

This is an open ball, the closed ball would then have to be with  $\leq$

I take $a,b\in B(x,r)$ then $d(x,a)<r$ and $d(x,b)<r$ I now have to show $d(x,x_t)<r\iff \sqrt{(x_1-(a_1+t(b_1-a_1)))^2+...+(x_n-(a_n+t(b_n-a_n)))^2}<r$

My idea was to loke at the equation componentwise but I don't know how to continue:

I look at one summand under the root sign, it has the form

$(x_i-a_i-t(b_i-a_i))^2=(x_i+(t-1)a_i-tb_i)^2=(x_i-\big{[}(1-t)a_i+tb_i\big{]})$

If I could raise the absolute value in $(...)$ above then I could maybe show with what I already know that the new raised Expression is $<r$. But I don't know how.

Can someone give me a hint how I can solve this excercise please?

Comment: Use the triangle inequality for the distance $d$. (That is, $d(u,v) \le d(u,w) + d(w,v)$.)

Comment: I guess the reason why they wrote "runde Bälle" is that "Bälle" just refers to balls with respect to a given metric. So they wrote runde Bälle to stress the fact that we are using the euclidean metric (balls with respect to other metrics might not be convex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lVert a\rVert,\lVert b\rVert<r$, then for each $t\in[0,1]$,\begin{align}\bigl\lVert a+t(b-a)\bigr\rVert&=\bigl\lVert(1-t)a+tb\bigr\rVert\\&\leqslant(1-t)\lVert a\rVert+t\lVert b\rVert\\&<(1-t)r+tr\\&=r.\end{align}If you have $\leqslant $ instead of $<$, it is similar.